# Undefined error when filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I am trying to present schools in cities and cities in states using a filter in Django:

```
State Page
--- City
-----School
-----School
```

However, I keep getting an undefined (NameError) error when I try to filter using the state__state_name model field. The state_name model field contains the name of the states. All 50 US states in there.

Here is the error:

```
NameError: name 'state_state_name' is not defined
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .models import School, State

class StateDetail(ListView):
    model = StateArticle
    template = 'state_detail.html'

    context_object_name = 'state_article'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StateDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['school_list'] = School.objects.filter(address__city__state=state_state_name).order_by('city_name')
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    summary_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary_name

class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    state_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    city_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name

class Address(models.Model):
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    street_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street_address

class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    professional_school = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True)
    school_summary = models.ForeignKey(Summary, null=True)
    school_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

class StateArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=69, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=155, default='')
    state_article_summary = models.ForeignKey(Summary, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=69, null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('state_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from .views import StateDetail

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', StateDetail.as_view(), name='state_detail'),

]
```

How can I filter schools by the city and then filter that city by the state? I am slowly learning how to use django. Any help you offer will be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't  defined a FK/M2M relation between schools and addresses

Comment: You wrote "_when I try to filter using the state__state_name model field_" but your code does not show where did you try filtering using that field.

Comment: After your edit, your problem seems to be that you don't have a variable named `state_state_name` in your code. Post the relevant portions of your code, not a single line with error and explain what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to display a list of schools by city on a page that lists all of the schools in a state...In my State model, the state_name field contains the state names that I would like to use to organize the schools by city.

Comment: the right hand side in `filter()` is where a variable declared in Python belongs, ie `filter(db_column=python_variable)`. Your code is trying to use a variable called `state_state_name`, which does not exist. You have to declare it first.

Comment: Where would I define the state_name variable? Can you show me an example as to how you would do it?

Comment: add your `urls.py` first please

Comment: urls added. There is only one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like copy-pasted from somewhere else, and now you want us to make it work for you. Please go read how does [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) work, there are several issues in the code.

- if you want to list the cities, the `model` property in the `View` should be `City` then, not `StateArticle`.
- the named parameter in your `urls.py` is called `slug`, which is misleading, as there is no slug anywhere in your `State` or `City` or in any other relevant model.
- if you want to filter the queryset in your view, there is a method called `get_queryset()`. By default return all records, so you want to override it, call the parent, and then call `filter()` on the queryset from the parent.

and finally to your question about undefined variable:

to make the variable available, you have to declare it first. So let's say you have the state name in the parameter `slug` from the url. It will be available in the view via `self.kwargs['slug']`. So you want to use it to obtain the `State` first, and then you can use that object to filter your queryset, eg.

```
# this is a silly implementation, but the variable has now what you need
state = State.objects.get(state_name=self.kwargs['slug'])
# if you insist on the variable from your code, here you go
state_state_name = state.state_name
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to make this work for several days. I believe you helped me before. I thought I had it. I didn't. I kept plugging away until you helped again. Thanks, again.